# How to trigger mouse events like mouseup,mousedown with selenium

Tags: selenium, mouseevent, mousedown, mouseup

How can we trigger mouse events like mousedown, mouseup and mouse move with selenium?
I know this way:

```
Locatable locat = (Locatable) we;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseDown(locat.getCoordinates());
```

But this works only for Chrome browser, not for other browsers.Can anyone suggest methods to trigger these events?

Comment: Use the Actions class.https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: In Actions class, we have keyup and keydown events.I couldnt find mouse up , mousedown and mouse move in Actions

Comment: In the Actions class, there is moveByOffset and moveToElement.

`moveByOffset(x-offset, y-offset) Moves the mouse from its current position (or 0,0) by the given offset.

Parameters:

x-offset- horizontal offset. A negative value means moving the mouse left.

y-offset- vertical offset. A negative value means moving the mouse down.
moveToElement(toElement) Moves the mouse to the middle of the element. 

Parameters:

toElement- element to move to.`